# Pyrazole iodination

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, aromatic-compounds, nucleophilic-substitution

I'm now working on synthesizing 4-Iodo-1,3-dimethyl-1H-pyrazole starting from 1,3-Dimethylpyrazole, iodine, and hydrogen peroxide. I think the mechanism is just a simple aromatic nucleophilic substitution reaction, but I'm not sure if the mechanism is same because of 2 nitrogen atoms in aromatic ring. The reagents are pretty much same as from the textbook.

[image]